# can't create superuser with custom userprofile

Tags: django

I tried to do "./manage.py syncdb", and I get prompted to create a superuser, but It fails:

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/src/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 397, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/src/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 390, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/src/django-trunk/django/core/management/base.py", line 240, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/src/django-trunk/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/src/django-trunk/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 141, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Here is my userprofile:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager, AbstractUser



class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    membernumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, unique=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)    

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'membernumber'

    objects = UserManager()
```

Maybe the problem is that I have run "syncdb" and having "blank=True" on the unique field?

Answer (score 2):

You should define your own Manager to instead of the default `UserManager`;

As your example:

```
class MyManager(UserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, membernumber,email,password,**extra_fields):
        super().create_superuser(membernumber,email,password,**extra_fileds)
        #or do something to save your model by yourself;
```

Why we need do this?

Just look your error dump

`self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)`

So when you run `python manage.py createsuperuser` on your shell,after you input your `membernumber`,`password`,`email` value,then your `user_data` will become:

`{'membernumber':'Garreth','password':'123456','email':'like@gamil.com'}`

but `UserManager.create_superuser` need `username` param,your miss it!! So you get that error.

Here is the the source of `UserManager.create_superuser`(refer 1)

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

And some source about what run when you `python manage.py createsuperuser`(refer 2)

```
if username:
    user_data[self.UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD] = username
    user_data['password'] = password

    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database)
        \.create_superuser(**user_data)
    if options['verbosity'] >= 1:
        self.stdout.write("Superuser created successfully.")
```

Suggestion:

If you still want to exec `python manager.py createsuperuser`,you should **NEVER** define a custom UserModel that inherit `AbstractBaseUser`,because `django.contrib.admin`,`django.contrib.auth` use too many `AbstractUser` Model attrs like `is_active`,`is_superuser`,so you will get many errors when you visit `yousite.com/admin` on browser.

Refers:

1.https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L156

2.https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py#L170

Answer (score 0):

In this [book](https://django.2scoops.org/) said:

> Option 2: Subclass AbstractUser:
>
> > Choose this option if you like Django’s User model fields the way they are, but need extra fields.

Maybe you have to subclass AbstractBaseUser. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) or a full example.

***Edit***

`USERNAME_FIELD` should be used if you want to use another username field. If you want that, you must subclass [`AbstractBaseUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) instead of `AbstractUser`, because the last one already has defined a `USERNAME_FIELD`

Hope helps!

Comment: AbstractBaseUser is used for making a "new" baseUser, Im just trying to add some extra fields to the user, and are using AbstractUser. But I tried to change it to AbstractBaseUser, but got the same error.

Comment: I think that the problem is the `USERNAME_FIELD = 'membernumber'` line

Comment: yes! the `USERNAME_FIELD = 'membernumber'` was causing the problem!

Comment: Someone tell me what was the problem with the `USERNAME_FIELD` line

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a bug, it needs to be fixed. Alternatively, you can create the user with `python manage.py shell`

`from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model get_user_model().objects.create_superuser(username="admin", password="password")`